# Gradle compile project manifest empty

Tags: java, build, compilation, gradle

I have a probleme with my build.gradle, it's compile fine but when i try to execute the .jar the console give me this: "no manifest manifest attribute..."

it's my bluid.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
group = "com.xxx.xxx.xxx"
archivesBaseName = "xxx"
version = "0.1"

task pack(type: Jar, dependsOn: 'jar') {

   inputs.files jar.archivePath;

   jar {
    baseName = 'xxxx'
    version =  '0.1'
   }

   manifest {
    attributes(
        "Manifest-Version"       : "1.0",
            "Main-Class"             : "com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
        )
   }

   doLast {
     manifest.writeTo("${buildDir}/MANIFEST.MF")
     project.ant {
       taskdef name: "jarjar", classname: "com.tonicsystems.jarjar.JarJarTask", classpath: configurations.tools.asPath
       jarjar(jarfile: archivePath, manifest: "${buildDir}/MANIFEST.MF") {
     fileset(dir : "${buildDir}/classes")
     fileset(dir : "${buildDir}/resources/main")

     configurations.runtime.files.each { jarjarFile ->
       zipfileset(src: jarjarFile) {
         // WARNING: MUST keep META-INF/DgmInfo, META-INF/services, ...  which are needed by Groovy
       }
     }

     rule pattern: "*", result: "@0"
       }
   }
}


configurations {
    tools
}

dependencies {
    tools files("${rootDir}/tools/jarjar-1.4.jar")
    compile files("${rootDir}/lib/bluecove-2.1.0.jar")
    compile files("${rootDir}/lib/bluecove-gpl-2.1.0.jar")
}

}
```

I don't write the whole code, I don't really know to code a gradle script,
someone help ? :)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this part:
`"Main-Class"             : "com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"`
in reality is pointing to a valid Java class that has a main method inside, and the class is on your class path?

If yes, unzip your output jar, find META-INF folder and check what is inside MANIFEST.MF and tell us.

Comment: The path is src/main/java/package/package/Xxx.java, so I thinks it's good, but i'm not really sure :(

Comment: Ok, so assuming that the values that you have given are correct and not obfuscated by you, because you are code shy, the value in your build.gradle file should be: "Main-Class"             : "package.package.Xxx"

Comment: Check this tutorial by the way: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-our-first-java-project/